# OIDC - Extra parameters in sign-in URL query string

Tags: javascript, c#, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have a Javascript client which uses OIDC for authentication. I'm using the authorization code flow. Here is a code snippet:

```
var config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope:"openid profile web_api",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/index.html"
};
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
```

I would like to be able to add extra parameters in the ***config*** object above which would be available in the query string of the URL that I have access to in the Login method of my Authorization Server (http://localhost:5000/Account/Login):

(C# code):

```
// <summary>
/// Entry point into the login workflow
/// </summary>
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

(I can access the URL query string in the code above by both the ***returnUrl*** parameter or the **HttpContext.Request.Query** property)

Unfortunately, if I set new (non-standard) parameters in the ***config*** object on the Javascript client, their are not passed to the URL query string.

Contextualizing: The reason I need this feature is because there are extra parameters that are mandatory for me to authenticate the user, besides username and password. However, these parameters are not explicitly informed by the user. They have their values assigned inside the client Javascript code (Ex: the device ID (like a cell phone's IMEI) of the client). If there is any other easier way to achieve this, I would be glad to know about.

I'm able to achieve this using Postman, based on [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2523) discussion on GitHub:

Because in Postman you can change the authorization endpoint URL to:

http://MyAuthorizationEndpoint?paramName=paramValue

Ex: http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize?device_id=XYZ

But I'm not able to do this in the Javascript client because I do not specify the authorization endpoint explicitly, only the **authority** (as seen in the ***config*** object above).

OBS: I don't intend to use any other type of authorization flow, like using an Extension Grant, since it's more insecure and not recommended.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution after reading [this](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/315) discussion. Method Oidc.UserManager.signinRedirect accepts an ***extraQueryParams*** argument that has this exact purpose:

(Javascript client):

```
mgr.signinRedirect({
        extraQueryParams: {
            device_id: "XYZ"
        },
    });
```

This is very useful for anyone searching for a solution for Authorization Code Flow in which you need to pass custom parameters for validation before issuing the code/token.